# proper pattern to use when passing an array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am currently reading `understanding pointers in c`, am at the section were the author talks about passing arrays to functions. Out of all the bellow patterns which is best to use and why ? , does it have anything to do with optimisation ?

```
#include <stdio.h>


void passAsPointerWithSize(int * arr, int size) {
  for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  }
}


void passAsPointerWithoutSize(int * arr) {
  while ( *arr ) {
    printf("%d\n", *arr);
    arr++;
  }
}

void passWithoutPointerWithSize( int arr [] , int size) {
  for ( int i = 0; i <= size; i++ ) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  }
}



void passWithoutPointerUsingWhile(int arr []) {
  int i = 1;
  while ( arr[i] ) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[i++]);
  }
}


int main() {
  int size = 5;
  int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5};
  passAsPointerWithSize(arr, size);
  passAsPointerWithoutSize(arr);
  passWithoutPointerWithSize(arr, size);
  passWithoutPointerUsingWhile(arr);
}
```

i compiled it with `-std=gnu11 -O3`

Comment: The ones without `size` invoke **undefined behaviour**, so don't use those ones.  `<=` should be `<`.  Once you fix that, the two with `size` are equivalent.

Comment: How come those `while` loops gonna stop? And in another `for` you are accessing out of bound. So far I just see one of them is working correctly.

Comment: you are correct, the second one was outputing 3276 after it's executing , until i compiled with `-O3` @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: @coderredoc they all executed fine

Comment: Executing fine is not the same as correct code. 3 of the loops are wrong.

Comment: @coderredoc then which is the best pattern to use

Comment: `While`'s are impractical for this case...`for` works correctly only if you access it within limits.

Comment: Are you sure the `passWithoutPointerUsingWhile` has `int i = 1` in it, not `int i = 0`, and the `passWithoutPointerWithSize` uses `<=` instead of `<`?

Comment: All but the 1st invoke UB, by reading beyond `arr`'s  bounds.

Comment: @alk.: Only one them is correct. Rest are invoking UB.

Comment: @coderredoc: already fixed, after having had a 2nd look ... :}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of function parameters, `int arr []` is the same as `int *arr` because *when an array is passed as a function argument to a function parameter, it **decays into a pointer to its first element***.

So the following declaration:

```
void foo(int * arr, int size);
```

is equivalent to:

```
void foo(int arr[], int size);
```

When it comes to the question whether you need the `size` parameter, you need it in order to determine the length of the array, unless:

- there is a special value stored in the array that act as an indicator for the *end of array* (the callee would be responsible for checking against this indicator).
- the length of the array is already known to the caller.

Otherwise, how could you possibly know how many elements the array contains?

---

> Out of all the bellow patterns which is best to use and why ?

With the points above in mind, the only thing you can always choose is whether to use the `int *` syntax or the `int []` one for the function parameter.

Although both are equivalent (as explained above), some people may argue that using `int *` could suggest that there is at most one element, whereas `int []` could suggest thet there there is at least one element and there could be more than one.

> does it have anything to do with optimization ?

No, or at least, not directly, whether you need the `size` parameter is actually a matter of whether the size of the array is known by the caller or it can be obtained by means of a stored *end-of-array* indicator.

Comment: Even with the indicator the code will be wrong...think if you get that indicator in the middle of the array/

Comment: @coderredoc someone could even forget to store the indicator.

Comment: @coderredoc There is nothing inherently wrong with an agreed-upon indicator, apart from losing the ability to use that indicator as a "regular" value. This is the convention behind C strings - you can embed `'\0'` in the middle of `char` array, with the understanding that all C string functions will treat it as the end-of-string marker.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight.: Yes but this is not char array and yes we can have that behavior. You are right it's not inherently wrong but then yes OP's array doesnt contain `0`'s. So sure UB.

Comment: @coderredoc OP is a different story, he has managed to make several typos while copying code from the article (I think `i=1` and `<=` are typos). Perhaps he thought the content of the array didn't matter, and replaced zero at the end with `5` :-)

Answer (score 3):

#### First see which one is correct! (based on what you posted)

```
void passAsPointerWithSize(int * arr, int size) {
  for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  }
}
```

This is the one **not** invoking Undefined Behavior.

The ones using `while` won't stop unless they get an element having value `0`. What if the array has no `0`'s ? Then it will access way beyond the memory (which is the case here). Perhaps this echos back to a time when strings used to be marked with zeros at their end, in any case, it's bad practice.

The other for loop is looping till `index<=size` accessing array index out of bounds when `index = size`, again, undefined behavior.

#### Now back to your question..

***The syntax `func(int arr[],..)` is the same as `func(int* arr,...)` on the context of passing a 1D-array to a function***. Arrays are passed as pointers - it doesn't matter how you specify the signature.

Looping? - it's just a matter of choice.

#### Typos and other things...

Typos are the `<=` or the `i=1` initialization in one of the functions. did you not want to print the 0-th element? Well `i=1` and then you start looping - it missed the `0-th` element.

*A compiler, when passed an array, deals with a pointer to the first element of the array no matter how you write it so the form doesn't matter*

#### How do I know the size of the array passed?

In any of the cases - when you pass an array to a function as a pointer - there is no way to know the length of the array unless you have some placeholder which marks the end of the array. If that is not the case then you have to obviously somehow know the length of it - which is what you do when you pass a parameter named `size` in the function.

#### Readability + Choice + ...

Writing it as `arr[]` can be used to convey the meaning that it is an array when we will deal with that pointer. You may skim through the code and get an idea about what it is getting as arguments and what it will possibly do. One may argue that a comment can still serve that purpose - that's where choice comes into the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, some of them won't work (what do you mean by the condition *arr for instance? are you trying to bring back null terminated strings? don't!)

But, actually the fastest one (barring some crazy compiler optimization which I for one have not seen in practice) if you don't care about order is iterating backwards

```
void passAsPointerWithSize(int *arr, int size) {
  for ( int i = size - 1; i > 0; i-- ) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  }
}
```

That's because it saves a whole CPU clock cycle every loop, since after you reduce i (i--) the answer of comparing to zero (i > 0) is already stored in the registers

Comment: Fair, I didn't know there was an alternative spelling, thanks